UI package in Turborepo produces TS error intermittently - Could not find a declaration file for module
I'm trialling a Turborepo at the moment, and struggling with a TS error I can't seem to solve.
The error reads:

Could not find a declaration file for module '@myapp/ui'.
'C:/myapp/packages/ui/dist/index.mjs' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try npm i --save-dev @types/myapp__ui if it exists or add a new
declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module '@myapp/ui';

My main issue is that this is intermittent. Sometimes the error is there, and other times it just goes away upon restarting the TS Server, and then stay away for several hours.
Here is my project structure:
.
├── apps
│   └── web
│       ├── src
│       │   └── [lang]
│       │       ├── layout.tsx
│       │       └── page.tsx
│       ├── package.json
│       └── tsconfig.json
├── packages
│   └── ui
│       ├── dist
│       ├── src
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── tsup.config.ts
│       └── tsconfig.json
├── package.json
└── turbo.json

The contents of my packages/ui/package.json:
{
  "name": "@myapp/ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "main": "./dist/index",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.mts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": {
        "types": "./dist/index.d.mts",
        "default": "./dist/index.mjs"
      }
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsup --format esm --minify",
    "dev": "tsup --format esm --minify --watch",
    "check-types": "tsx --noEmit",
    "lint": "eslint src/ --max-warnings 0",
    "ui:add": "pnpm dlx shadcn-ui@latest add"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "next": "^14.1.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@myapp/eslint-config": "workspace:*",
    "@myapp/tailwind-config": "workspace:*",
    "@myapp/typescript-config": "workspace:*",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "tsup": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }      
}

I've tried changing the "types" to "dist/index" which works temporarily, and then the error returns, and then vice versa if I change it to "dist/index.d.mts".
The correct index.d.mts is indeed in the dist folder, and all appears to be correct within that.
Here is my tsup.config.ts:
import { defineConfig, Options } from "tsup"

export default defineConfig((options: Options) => ({
  entry: ["src/**/*.tsx"],
  format: ["esm"],
  esbuildOptions(options) {
    options.banner = {
      js: '"use client"',
    }
  },
  dts: true,
  clean: true, // Clears the dist
  external: ["react", "next-intl"],
  ...options,
}))

